The answer is not ___
This is part 2, see for part 1: The answer is not wrong

The answer is not ___



3rd
4th
5th
1st
3rd
1st
1st
4th
















Just like the previous puzzle, this is just so tidy! Thanks!

To find the answer here, first identify the items pictured. Here, we have:

 GIFTBAG (3rd), CHURCH (4th), BITCOIN (5th), METEOR (1st), SOLDIER (3rd), EGG (1st), FISH (1st), DENTIST (4th).

Let's do the obvious first thing and...

 ...use the numbers listed and look at the nth letters of each word:

 GI[F]TBAG, CHU[R]CH, BITC[O]IN, [M]ETEOR, SO[L]DIER, [E]GG, [F]ISH, DEN[T]IST.

 With the leading phrase, we can see here that "The answer is not FROM LEFT."

So there's an obvious alternative to try...

 How about looking at the nth letters from the right of each word? This time, we get:

 GIFT[B]AG, CH[U]RCH, BI[T]COIN, METEO[R], SOLD[I]ER, EG[G], FIS[H], DEN[T]IST.

 This spells "BUT RIGHT"!

So putting this all together...

 "The answer is not FROM LEFT... BUT RIGHT!" In other words, the answer here - in an echo to the linked previous question - is once more 'RIGHT'! (Only this time as an antonym to 'left' rather than 'wrong'...)


This is what I got but I can’t explain the word tag I would be highly surprised if this was all to it.

@PDT I think the final answer if one single word is merely rot13(evtug) - this would symbolically echo the answer from the linked previous question...

Ah shoot I should’ve just posted my answer then lol

Immediately after having looked at the part one, I genuinely really love this puzzle. It's just so darn neat!
